# Objc class and Swift protocol have conflicing names. How can I use both?

Tags: swift, objective-c

So I have a class `MyCell`. It inherits from `NSTextFieldCell` and implements `NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol`. The issue is that `NSTextFieldCell` defines a `var cellSize: NSSize` property. And `NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol` requires a `func cellSize() -> NSSize` function.

I'm looking for a way around this, because I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Method 'cellSize()' with Objective-C selector 'cellSize' conflicts with getter for 'cellSize' from superclass 'NSCell' with the same Objective-C selector
```

```
class NewCell: NSTextFieldCell, NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol {
  func cellSize() -> NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: 40, height: 24)
  }

 override var cellSize: NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: 40, height: 24)
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to use `NSTextFieldCell` and `NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol` in one class?

Comment: @Willeke I have tokens in my text, and I want to respond to certain events. NSTextAttachmentCell makes it much easier to put attachments/cells into an NSAttributedString, but it's really more focused on images than on text. NSTextFieldCell (or really NSTokenFieldCell is what I want), has more text focused methods/delegate functions.

Answer (score 0):

*Theoretically* you can work around this particular error with:

```
protocol NSTextAttachmentCellProtocolAlternate: NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol {
    var cellSize: NSSize { get }
}
class NewCell: NSTextFieldCell, NSTextAttachmentCellProtocolAlternate {
    ...
}
```

But that won't get you far.

At this point you will be hitting errors about conflicting method signatures between the `NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol`'s

```
func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView?)
```

and `NSCell`'s

```
open func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)
```

Guys at Apple could have done more consistent job with the `_Nullable` markers when exposing stuff to Swift. But they didn't.

That's a strong indicator you should rethink your approach as it becomes an uphill battle.